# $(x^3+x+1)^{-1} \mod (x^4+x+1)$ over $\text{GF}(2)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, cryptography

$(x^3+x+1)^{-1} \mod (x^4+x+1)$ over $\text{GF}(2)$

I understand well how to solve the equation without inverse but don't know how to solve it with inverse.

Comment: Just find a polynomial $g$ with $g(x)(x^3+x+1)\equiv 1 \bmod x^4+x+1$ using the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Or use [a suitable discrete logarithm table](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619). The table in my answer shows that $x^3+x+1\equiv x^7$. As $x^{15}\equiv1$ we find the inverse to be ______ (you fill in the blank).

Answer (score 2):

For a problem with bigger polynomials, I'd want to try fancier tools. But in this problem, I'd be tempted to compute

\begin{align}
   A &= (x^3+x+1)(1) \bmod x^4+x+1 \\
   B &= (x^3+x+1)(x) \bmod x^4+x+1 \\
   C &= (x^3+x+1)(x^2) \bmod x^4+x+1 \\
   D &= (x^3+x+1)(x^3) \bmod x^4+x+1  
\end{align}

and then see what linear combination of $A, B, C, D$ adds up to $1$. Then the inverse is the same linear combination of $1, x, x^2, x^3$.

(Some of these, like $A$, don't actually take work to compute. We can stop at $D$ because $x^4 \equiv x+1 \pmod{x^4+x+1}$, so a hypothetical $E$ would just be the same as $A+D$.)

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. May I ask where do you get the 1, x, x^2, x^3?

Comment: Because any polynomial is a sum of $1, x, x^2, \dots$ with some coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Just perform the *extended Euclidean algorithm* in $\mathbf F_2$ to obtain a Bézout's relation between $X^4+X+1$ and $X^3+X+1$:
\begin{array}{r| lll}
r(X) & u & v & q \\ \hline
X^4+X+1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
X^3+X+1&1 & 0 & X \\ \hline
X^2+1 & X & 1 & X \\
1 & 1 +X^2 & X \\
\hline
\end{array}

Therefore, $(X^2+1)(X^3+X+1)+X(X^4+X+1)=0 $.